# Access to events?

Tags: asp.net, controls

i have a question about generating images at runtime which are also links. Ok, so what i was going to do was create an ImageButton, and then set the onClick event to something such as:

```
window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/')
```

Which means it would look like:

```
newImage.Click += (window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/'));
```

But then i realised that this doesnt work, because it looks for a method which matches the event delagate.

So my question is, is this the best way to achieve what i want, and if so, how can i make it work?

Another option that came in my head would be to wrap the image in an  tag, but i think this way its better.

Thanks

Comment: Since opening a new window is a client-side event, why try to do this in server-side code at all?  Why not just do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You cant do it in javascript, i explained in the question! The event onClick, looks for a method with an object and eventArgs, you cant feed it javascript.

Comment: I guarantee you that you can open a browser window in response to a click even on a DOM element in JavaScript.  In fact, using client-side scripting is the _only_ way to open a new browser window.  Server-side code has no means of telling the client to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx):

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/'); return false;" ImageUrl="MyButton.png" />
```

This property is a string, not event, and you can also assign it from within the code behind:

```
ImageButton1.OnClientClick = "window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/'); return false;";
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I never knew about this one. What is the difference between them? The one works on the client side and on causes a postback?

Comment: No problem, it's no trivial thing - took me some time to learn about it as well in the beginning. The attribute `OnClick` is "complex" and translated to complicated JS code causing form submission thus Post Back.. the `OnClientClick` is "simple" string attribute rendered as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to use server-side code to tell the client to open a browser window, you can't.  The server-side code has no means of telling the client to do that.  The only thing you'd be able to do from server-side code is emit client-side that does this.  And in that case, why use the server-side code at all?

Using jQuery for example, you can attach the click event like this:

```
<!-- page header (including loading jQuery), other stuff that's before the image, etc. -->
<img src="/path/to/image" alt="some text" id="imgOpenWindow" />
<!-- the rest of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imgOpenWindow').click(function(){
      window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/');
    });
  });
</script>
```

If for some reason you *need* to use an `ImageButton` control for this then it would look like this:

```
<!-- page header (including loading jQuery), other stuff that's before the image, etc. -->
<asp:ImageButton run="server" id="imgOpenWindow" ImageUrl="/path/to/image" AlternateText="some text" />
<!-- the rest of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= imgOpenWindow.ClientID %>').click(function(){
      window.open('http://www.themagicfinger.com/');
    });
  });
</script>
```

But I'm not sure what the behavior would be with the post-back.  It might override the JavaScript handler (by posting back before your handler is executed) or post-back after the window opens, etc.  I would consider that behavior to be undefined and unreliable.  An `Image` control will do the trick, though, if you don't need the button post-back capabilities.